# How to open chm file from a button in VS Lightswitch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

What sort of code do i need to put in a button's **can_execute() method** in order to open a .chm help file i made for my lightswitch application and how will i make sure that even after publishing the whole application... the .chm file is transferred into the user's computer automatically and it stays in the right directory?  ..... Thanks!

```
 partial void Help_Execute()
    {
        // Write your code here.

        if (AutomationFactory.IsAvailable)
        {
            dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Shell.Application");
            shell.ShellExecute("C:/Users/Thuto/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/ElectricalContructors/ElectricalContructors/Client/Resources/SparkHelpDocumentation.chm", "", "", "open", 1);
        }
        else
        {
            this.ShowMessageBox("Automation not available");
        }

    }
```

After a hours of trying to find a better way i tried this and it worked but i want to know the proper way of doing it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article about making images embedded resources on the Client side. I haven't tried it with a .chm but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/06/15/adding-static-images-and-text-on-a-lightswitch-screen.aspx